# Using LINQ to return List from 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add two lists in Linq so addedList[x] = listOne[x] + listTwo[x]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511843/how-do-i-add-two-lists-in-linq-so-addedlistx-listonex-listtwox)

I have 2 IList objects with equal number of rows

```
IList<double> A;
IList<double> B;
```

I am looking to return an IList where i perform a calculation foreach, for simplicity lets assume i just want to add the 2 values A[n] + B[n] for each item in the lists.

How would you do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) extension method:

```
var result = A.Zip(B, (a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: just a note, it only came in on 4.

Comment: @KeithNicholas, yes, but it's easy to implement yourself if necessary ;)

Comment: sure :)  but worth knowing incase you can't work out why your code won't compile :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas After 2 years, I think it's reasonable to assume at least 4.0 unless stated otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly:

```
A.Zip(B, (x, y) => x + y).ToList();
```

Though as always, think about whether it's possible to not have to put it into a list, first, and leave out the `.ToList()` if you can.